# Qual è il senso di "dritto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Rocco gli ha spiegato che i **dritti** hanno tutti un altro nome. Non usano mai fra loro quello di battesimo. Usano un aggettivo, Fat, Slim, Il Lercio, o un animale, Hog (Porco), Grillo, Pallottelammerda (Scarabeo), Zecca, o un episodio – Otacèro (Capogiro), Agliumino (Fiammifero), Coal. Oppure una versione americana del primo nome, come Rusty, che in realtà si chiama Oreste, o Elmer che in realtà si chiama Adelmo. Alla Bongiorno nessuno sa chi sia Rocco. Lo chiamano Merluzzo.

Ho cercato il termine "dritto" in alcuni dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere molto senso nel contesto di questo brano.

Ho visto che questo vocabolo appare in altri parti dello stesso libro, come, per esempio in questi passaggi:

> Non dar retta ai padroni e ai preti – il lavoro abbrutisce. La conosci la filastrocca dei **dritti**? Con arte e con inganno vivrò metà dell’anno, con inganno e con arte vivrò l’altra parte.

> Figuriamoci se ha paura di un orso con gli orecchini, lui che ha attraversato l’oceano da solo, ha dormito a Central Park dove neanche i **dritti** hanno il coraggio di entrare dopo il tramonto.

> L’umanità si divide in due categorie, gli uàppi e i tòtari – cioè i tosti e i minchioni, i **dritti** e i fessi, i duri e i babbei. I tòtari esistono per servire gli altri e pagare per loro. È sempre stato cosí. In America come in Italia. Ma qui non esistono sfumature – bianco o nero – e il grigio non è stato inventato.

Potreste aiutarme a capire il significato dell'uso che si fa di "dritto" in questo romanzo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dritto1/):

> c. Abile, furbo, scaltro, capace di ottenere ciò che vuole e privo di
>   scrupoli; per lo più con uso sostantivato: è un d.!; non fare il
>   dritto!

Comment: Hai ragione, @persson! Che bello vederti di nuovo qui!